# How to write a table reference working with rjdbc?

Tags: r, hive, rjdbc, dbplyr

I am working with really big data with `R`. My data is on `Hive` and I am using `rjdbc`. I am thinking of using a reference table on R because its impossible to load the table onto R even just using 10% sample. I am using the `tbl` function from `dplyr`.

```
transaction <- tbl(conn,"transaction")
```

R gave me an error message :

> the dbplyr package is required to communicate with the database
>   backends.

I am using a remote computer and it's impossible to install package on this R version. 
Any other solutions to solve the problem?

Comment: If you are reading only a subset of dataset, then create a subset table in hive `dbSendUpdate(hivecon, "drop table if exists yourdb.tmptable")` then create a subset table with `dbSendUpdate` from the main table and read it with `dbGetQuery` i.e. `dbGetQuery(hivecon, "SELECT * FROM yourdb.tmptable")`  Make sure that it is kerberos compliant

Comment: I tried this method but still, the data is too big and R runs extremely slow on that...